# Writing a summarized validation javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, css

I have an HTML page on the admin site for managing user on a HTML/Javascript/PHP system that runs on browsers. I have close to 20 inputboxes because on one page i have combined several forms of new_user, forgot_password, Change_password and Edit_user_details.

This code is what i used to check the username's empty field, this means i have to write 20 of this lines;  
My concern is`-->` How do i write a short, summarized but effective `javascript code` to check on empty fields. (I will also need to validate fields like digits, numbers, length, emails etc)

```
function RequiredFields(){
 var username=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
  if (username==""||username==null){
     alert("empty username")
     document.login.username.focus();
     if(document.all||document.getElementById){
         document.login.username.style.background="pink";
    }
     return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: A common pattern is to give each field a class or series of class names pertaining to what the data of the field should contain. IE: For a currency field you could set `class="required currency"`. You could then `getElementsByClassName` and iterate over the nodelist to validate each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to check for empty fields, have a look at this code:

```
function Validate() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if (this.value=="")
        alert('Value Required');
        });
    }
```

To validate things like emails, numbers etc, you would need to write a separate function for those particular text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/TgCbB/1/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="required" data-default="User Name"/>
<input type="text" id="email" class="required email" data-default="Email"/>
<input type="text" id="digits" class="required digits" data-default="Integer"/>
```

The important thing to note here is the `class` attribute, which indicates how it should be validated. (You could do this with a data- attribute, which would be better, but I used class for backwards compatibility).

You can now, with plain javascript, validate like so:

```
function validate(e){
    var invalid = [];

    var required = document.getElementsByClassName("required");
    for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++){
        var req = required[i];
        var val = req.value || "";
        var def = req.hasAttribute("data-default") ? req.getAttribute("data-default") : "";

        if (val == "" || val == def)
            invalid.push(req);

        req.className = req.className.replace(" invalid","");
    }

    var digits = document.getElementsByClassName("digits");
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
        var dig = digits[i];
        var val = Number(dig.value || "");
        var rem = val - Math.floor(val);

        if (rem != 0)
            invalid.push(dig);

        dig.className = dig.className.replace(" invalid","");
    }

    var emails = document.getElementsByClassName("email"),
        reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
        var em = emails[i];
        var val = em.value || "";

        if (!reg.test(val))
            invalid.push(em);

        em.className = em.className.replace(" invalid", "");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < invalid.length; i++){
        var inp = invalid[i];
        var cls = inp.className.replace(" invalid", "");

        inp.className = cls + " invalid";
    }
}
```

Note that the could be made less verbose, but I opted for readability. The concept is, get each item with the class name we're validating against, iterate over them, and then mark it as invalid if it doesn't pass validation.

Comment: Note that the regular expression I'm using isn't, by any means, the best to validate email. I just grabbed one real quick to whip up the proof of concept.